# Meteor: send message to user at hot code push

Tags: meteor

How can I let the user know when they are getting a hot code push?

At the moment the screen will go blank during the push, and the user will feel it's rather weird.  I want to reassure them the app is updating.

Is there a hook or something which I can use?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://forums.meteor.com/t/is-there-a-hot-code-push-live-reload-hook/7028) forum topic - specifically [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-using-a-custom-onmigrate-api) and [this package](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-migration).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the shortest solution I've found so far that doesn't require external packages:

```js
var ALERT_DELAY = 3000;
var needToShowAlert = true;

Reload._onMigrate(function (retry) {
  if (needToShowAlert) {
    console.log('going to reload in 3 seconds...');
    needToShowAlert = false;
    _.delay(retry, ALERT_DELAY);
    return [false];
  } else {
    return [true];
  }
});
```

You can just copy that into the client code of your app and change two things:

1. Replace the `console.log` with an alert modal or something informing the user that the screen is about to reload.
2. Replace `ALERT_DELAY` with some number of milliseconds that you think are appropriate for the user to read the modal from (1).

---

#### Other notes

- I'd recommend watching [this video](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-using-a-custom-onmigrate-api) on  Evented Mind, which explains what's going on in a little more detail.
- You can also read the comments in the [reload source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reload/reload.js) for further enlightenment.
- I can image more complex reload logic, especially around deciding when to allow a reload. Also see [this pacakge](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-migration/blob/master/migration.js) for one possible implementation.

Comment: Thanks @David great answer! Is this compatible with mdg:reload-on-resume?

Comment: I had a look at [the source](https://github.com/meteor/mobile-packages/blob/master/packages/mdg:reload-on-resume/reload-on-resume.js) and I think the answer is yes in terms of functionality but no in terms of user experience. If both callbacks are registered, on mobile, this one will alert the user but the other one will prevent the migration from happening until the app resumes. You'd be misinforming the user, so I'd pick one or the other. If you want them in the same project, you could put this one in a package and use something like `api.add_files("custom-reload.js", 'web.browser');`.

Comment: Good point. Though when the user resumes and their app forces them to update, it's also good to warn them at that point. Seems the best solution is to combine the two in a package - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could send something on [Meteor.startup()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_startup) in your client-side code.  I personally use [Bert](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/client-side-alerts-with-bert/) to toast messages.

Comment: `startup` will run after the migration has happened. I'd recommend reworking this answer using my comment above. I would, but I'm running out the door.

Comment: Ah interesting, didn't know this was available.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how to override this safely, so I think I'll let you answer it. :)

Comment: Done! This was a little more tricky than I had previously assumed.